# Creating a javascript variable that adds 1 when an event happens

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Context: I'm helping my friend create a political joke sort of website.

I need it to add 1 to a variable every time the onmouseover event is triggered.

```html
<img  src="tm.png" onmouseover='this.src="jc.png"'>
```

I have this so far but I need to find a way to link it with a function that will add 1 to itself when that event happens. I have multiple onmouseover events around the page so I need it to work for them all. I know how to make the variable but I am unsure on how to add 1 each time the onmouseover event happens, I am also unsure on how to add the function to the onmouseover event. Thanks

Comment: Should it increment only when an image fires the `mouseover` event or any other element? Every image or just one specific image? Should it increment for each image separately? Have you considered using the `mouseenter` event instead? Have you tried doing that with event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

```js
hoverCounter = 0;
```

```html
<img src="http://www.darbsterkitty.com/uploads/5/5/5/6/55568079/b8sk1f_orig.jpg" height="200px" onmouseover="hoverCounter++; console.log('hoverCounter: ' + hoverCounter)"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation and check whether the hovered element is an image.

```js
var count = 0;

addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == "IMG"){
    count++;
  }
  console.log(count);
})
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50?0"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50?1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="someImage1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" >
<img id="someImage2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" >

<br/>
Hover Count:
<input id="countDisplay" type="text"/>
```

JS:

```
 // Initial count
   var hoverCount = 0;

   // Function to increment
   function onHovered(event){
    hoverCount++;
     document.getElementById('countDisplay').value = hoverCount;
   }

   // Bind events
   document.getElementById('someImage1').onmouseover = onHovered;
    document.getElementById('someImage2').onmouseover = onHovered;
```